# How to do "quick structure" in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is an awesome `Quick Definition` which shows overlay dialog with definition of an object currently under the cursor (so you don't have to jump in files).

Is there a way how to access similar functionality, but rather `Quick Structure` (like the dock on left <kbd>ALT + 7</kbd>), but on the object under cursor (when cursor is not on its definition, but on an instance/type)?

Example:

```
fileA:
class A { ... }

fileB:
class B extends A { ... }

file:
const a: X<B> = ...;
```

In `file` when on `B` I could press shortcut and it would show me structure of the type `B` - so not only members defined in `B` (for which could be used `Quick Definition`), but also all inherited members (in this case defined in `A`).

Comment: f4 and then alt-7 ?

Comment: @vikingsteve That does a jump in file or open another file. I am looking for something similar to "Quick Def" which only opens small window on top of what I am currently doing and doesn't open a new tab with a  source file or scroll away in a current file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Navigate | File Structure` menu item. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> by default on the Mac.